# How to solve watson openscale problem”IllegalArgumentException”

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm building an environment by looking at this tutorial
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ai-openscale?topic=ai-openscale-gs-obj#gs-obj

Despite the model(credit risk model) provided by IBM, I get an error about the openscale dashboard
Failed to convert the JSON string 'array' to a data type. IllegalArgumentException

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide a small code snippet of what you have already done? It would help narrow down whats going wrong with your code.

Comment: i didt wirte code . just I just clicked the mouse according to this procedure  [https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ai-openscale?topic=ai-openscale-gs-obj#gs-obj]